# How to convert InnoDB tables to MyISAM using PHP or MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created my database with InnoDB Engine with Relashionships. But the 000webhost doesnt support InnoDB only supports MYISAM!

How can I covert the InnoDB to MYISAM? Is there any way to converted GUI or through command Lines (CMD)? And how to find the file which I can play with mysql through CMD?

I am using xampp package with PHP.

Comment: If your provider only supports MyISAM, you should probably get a better provider. It would also be a lot better if you didn't sound like you were running around with your hair on fire while posting questions. Panic doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I've used 000webhost some time back and they don't give support for db's since you are using free hosting

Comment: ya i am using free hosting but i did'nt get your last word if you explain it please 'you didn't sound like you were running around with your hair on fire while posting questions.'

Comment: [My SQL error: Database does not support the InnoDB Engine](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/31655-000-phpmyadmin-version-has-no-innodb.html#post170080)

Answer (score 1):

Quick Solution, change table engine type -

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**Wait**

what about `Transactions`, `data backups`, `table locks` if any..check this before something went extremely wrong ;)

Comment: I have relashionship between my tables PK---->FK

Comment: @TariqHashemee I was on my way to add this thing as well ;)

Comment: @swapnesh, your answer only to change storage engine for tables not for database.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin they are applied at tables..database can have both type of engines applied at different tables

Comment: @swapnesh, then whats the problem Tariq Hashemee facing???

Comment: @AdvaitAmin Question is "How to convert InnoDB tables to MyISAM using PHP or MYSQL?" ..." created my database with InnoDB Engine with Relationships." using default engine as INNODB now he wants to switch to MYISAM ..which actually applied at TABLES..import tables one by one ALTER engine then ..along with the constraints I mentioned to keep in mind...is thr something I missed ?????

Comment: @AdvaitAmin its all ok bro..just remember ..never hesitate to ask :)